# Character trouble in C

Tags: c

I'm a beginner to C and I'm having trouble understanding why this loop isn't reading my character datatype. What's wrong with my code?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    /************
     Declaration
    ************/

    int admin = 0; // Counts and administrates the loop
    char userInput; // Accounts for the name entered

    printf("Enter your  first name to the screen :");
    scanf("%c", &userInput);

    while (admin < 100)
    {
          printf("Hello, my name is %c!\n", userInput);
          admin++;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

Comment: A character datatype is a character datatype. It stores *a single character*. This is exactly what your program is written to input and then print 100 times (ignoring the mismatched variable name). It actually works fine, as written.

Comment: oops! I'll correct that, and yes it's supposed to be the same.

Comment: Also lacks a parenthesis. Compilers are unforgiving :p Use %s instead of %c.

Answer (score 3):

```
char userName[100];
```

and

```
scanf("%99s", userName);
```

and

```
printf("Hello, my name is %s!\n", userName);
```

Unless your username is one character long!

(in `C` a `char` is a single char. Clearly you want a `C` "string", so an array of chars (or you could `malloc` a piece of memory, but we will ignore that). So you declare an array of chars (I put a length of 100) but then you have to use `%s` with `scanf` and `printf`. As a sidenote you don't need the `&` to take the address of an array)

Someone else (Richard) has put `%99s` instead of `%s` because this prevents scanf from reading in names that are longer than 99 characters. Doing this would cause serious problems! He was VERY right! And I thank him. :-)

I'll add that I hope you know that a C string is "zero terminated" (the last character must be a `\0`) (a 0). For this reason an array of 100 chars can contain only a string long 99 (because the 0 terminator isn't counted).

Comment: You also probably don't want to print it out 100 times.

Comment: And you should probably use `fgets` (or specify `"%99s"` in the `scanf`) to avoid potential buffer overflows.

Comment: fgets (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) is safer than scanf.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. So the %s represents the char data type whenever we're trying to scan the variable then, correct? Just want to clarify.

Comment: @Chad: `%s` means that you're providing a `char` ***array*** big enough to store the string provided by the user.

Comment: @Kevin Stock: Not necessarily. For this application `scanf` is exactly as safe, if used properly (see Matteo Italia's comment)

Comment: @Chad Yes. There is a %something for each data type, plus some modifiers. Read here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/ For example the %99s means "read up to 99 characters for a string"

Comment: @AndreyT: on the other hand, the problem with the width specifier into the `scanf` format string is that it's a string and must be one character less than the size of the buffer, and there's no pratical method to keep the buffer size and the format string synced automatically. `fgets`, instead, accepts a normal `size_t` argument, so you can simply pass to it `sizeof(buffer)` and it "just works".

Comment: @Matteo: Yes -- unless `buffer` is a parameter, in which case it's really a pointer.  But in well-written code, you'll have another parameter that tells you how big the array is.

Comment: @Keith: of course, I was assuming that `buffer` was an array -- but it's a good thing that you highlighted this problem, it's quite a common error among beginners.

Comment: I quite love the fact that outside homework I haven't ever used scanf :-) Even when programming for the console, I use the command line, so I find the exchange about fgets and scanf very correct (and very important, because similar problems are present in many languages, problems about keeping "aligned" different components) but quite far from (my) reality.

Comment: @xanatos: actually, some people advocate to avoid `scanf` completely, relegating it just for tests, and to use "real" parsers for real data.

Comment: @Matteo: `scanf` does no overflow checking for numeric input; `scanf("%d", &n)` has undefined behavior if the input exceeds `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

The question you have asked i also faced it few months back. what i knew i am telling you.

when you use `%c` for `scanf()` it is able to take any 1 character input value. whether it is a number, an alphabet or your last pressed 'enter key' which is `\n` . It can take buffer values too. So in this case i different from `scanf()` and `%d` in which `scanf()` waits for a number and dont accepts an alphabet. But for `scanf()` and `%c` it can accept even the buffer values too. So to overcome this problem you can use these three methods

1) you can declare a  inbuilt function `fflush(stdin);` just before `scanf()`. like this

```
           printf("Enter your  first name to the screen :");
           fflush(stdin);
           scanf("%c", &userInput);
```

then your program will work fine. And dont forget to include the `<stdlib.h>` header file. this function is contained in that .Now i tell you demerits of this method. i have read at many places that this approach reduces the portability of the program so ANSI dont recommend this way.

2) you can declare an character array instead of a character variable. then `scanf()`. it also works fine.

3) this one is simplest. when you write statement like this `scanf("%c", &userInput);` I suggest you to write the statement like this `scanf(" %c", &userInput);` So can you detect the difference?? Actually an space is added just before the `%c` and now program works.

You can try all three methods and if any one of those doesnt work please notify me

Comment: `scanf`, as any C IO function, always takes values from the input buffer (IO in standard C is always buffered). The difference between `%c` and most of the other specifiers is that the others, before starting parsing their input, skip all the whitespace (which includes the `\n` often left by the previous inputs).